# Switching between UIWebViews with UIPageControl

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, uipagecontrol

The app that i am working on uses UIWebViews to display vimeo videos. Instead of displaying them all at once, i would like to be able to switch between them. What i would like to find out is whether i can use a UIPageControl to switch between them and how that can be achieved?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `UIScrollView` together with a `UIPageControl`. This can be tricky, but there are lots of tutorials out there, such as this one: [link](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIScrollView`, Apple provides excellent sample code:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795